# Extracting the Last N Bits from an Array of Bytes in C

Tags: arrays, c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have an array of unsigned characters in C:

```
unsigned char array[] = { 0xF0, 0xCC, 0xAA, 0xF0}; 
/* Represented as binary: 11110000 11001100 10101010 11110000 */
```

I'd like to extract the last N bits from this array and store them in an integer. For instance, if I want to extract the last 5 bits, the result should be:

```
int i = 32; /* Represented as binary: 10000 */
```

I tried using the BIGNUM library, but I found it to be overkill and a bit slow for this purpose. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this in C?

code attached:

```
unsigned char array[] = { 0xF0, 0xCC, 0xAA, 0xF0}; 
int i = 0; 
int j;
int totalBits = sizeof(array) * 8;  
int startBit = totalBits - 5;  

for (j = startBit; j < totalBits; j++) 
{
            i = i << 1;
            i = i | (array[j] & 1);
}
```

Comment: Would your `N` always be les than the bit-width of an `int`?

Comment: If you have tried writing this code yourself, it would be nice to see that work. SO is (usually) not a free code writing service... "_Is there a more efficient way to achieve this in C?_" ... Yes.

Comment: There are numerous posts on SO about combining bytes into bigger integers. Basically, to avoid endianness issues, you need to shift them in, sequentially. In your case, you would do that and also "mask out" the unwanted high bits of the last (MSB).

Comment: remeber about endiannes

Comment: @AdrianMole yes always

Comment: @Fe2O3 sure, attached code below

Comment: While bit-shifting in itself doesn't care about endianess, the expected format of the byte array (which one is the MS byte) does matter. Therefore you can't carry out this task without at least considering endianess. A common newbie problem is that they use a little endian CPU and then simply assume that numbers are stored in memory as "left to right" as you'd write them down.

Comment: If your array is always four bytes in little endian format you can do it with a simple branchless expression (not tested) (((((((uint64_t)array[3] << 8) + array[2]) << 8) + array[1]) << 8) + array[0]) & ((0x1UL << N) - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valiant effort! Thank you for showing your attempt.

I've added a few comments to your version:

```
unsigned char array[] = { 0xF0, 0xCC, 0xAA, 0xF0}; 
int i = 0; 
int j;
int totalBits = sizeof(array) * 8;  // currently meaning 32
int startBit = totalBits - 5;  // meaning 27 where '5' is the magic number wanted

for (j = startBit; j < totalBits; j++) 
{
            i = i << 1;
            i = i | (array[j] & 1); // Oops! there is no array[27]! Top element is array[3]!
}
```

Below is a rough draft of a version that seems to work:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char arr[] = { 0xF0, 0xCC, 0xAA, 0xF0 }; // Your array (add more! Try it out!)

    union { // providing for up to N = 64bits (on my system)
        unsigned char c[8];
        unsigned long l;
    } foo;

    foo.l = 0; // initialise

    size_t sz = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; // source byte count
    size_t n = 0; // destination byte count

    // wastefully copy as many bytes as are available until 'foo' is a full as possible
    // Notice the 'endian-ness' of index n going from 0 to 8.
    // Other hardware could change this to count downward, instead.
    for( size_t i = sz; i && n < sizeof foo; ) {
        foo.c[ n++ ] = arr[ --i ]; // grab one byte
        printf( "%x\n", foo.l ); // debugging
    }

    int N = 5;
    foo.l &= (1<<N)-1; // Mask off the low order N bits from that long

    printf( "%x\n", foo.l );

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Late caveat: maximum value of `N`, in this code, is `63`... One should add checking that `N` doesn't exceed the width of the accumulator `foo`, and if `N` is exactly that number, bypass the shift-and-mask operation...

PS: When playing with bit manipulation, it's often safer to used `unsigned` datatypes. Some C implementations apparently object to the sign bit being fiddled inappropriately.